# How can you turn off all alarms in a hidden iCal calendar?

Tags: macos, applescript, icalendar

I figured I'd ask here and see if anyone could offer anything, you guys are the faster answerers of anything. By default, when you hide a calendar in iCal (Snow Leopard) (clicking the checkbox), by default, every event is still armed. Like the alarms for hidden events will still activate at those times. I'd like them to turn off as long as the calendar is hidden. Is there maybe an applescript way to accomplish this?

Right now I'm trying a new anti-lazy workflow where I schedule tasks for myself ahead of time and force myself to switch to them (instead of saying "i'll do it later") by having the alert for each event be to activate a program that locks me out of my computer for 3 mins (Time Out). So far it's working well but being able to switch alarms on and off that quickly would really help.

Thanks!

Edit: I know you can right click and go to a dialog that turns off all alarms for that calendar, but it's so easy to forget to do that.

EditEdit: While we're at it, is there a way to move multiple events at once? You'd think this would be a given, but instead it just makes one new event where you dragged.